# Вычислить сумму членов бесконечного ряда

Tags: c, ряды

[image]

Помогите пожалуйста написать на си. Вроде не сложно, но с математикой не идут задачи у меня.

Comment: я могу ошибаться, но возможно эта задача решается гнездованием. (Рекуррентная формула)

Comment: Здравый смысл подсказывает мне, что "сумма членов бесконечного ряда" равна бесконечности.

Comment: Вы случайно не в школе учитесь? Или вы гуманитарий? Иначе бы знали про предел последовательности и про сходимость этой последовательности.

[Критерий сходимости Коши](http://school-collection.edu.ru/catalog/res/4e067d5a-f193-46cb-8167-ce516039e4ea/view/)

По нему:

    1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/(2*n) + ....

сходится, т.к. |1 / (2*n) - 1 / (2*n + 2)| = |2 / ((2*n + 2) * 2*n)| -> 0. Предел данной "суммы членов бесконечного ряда" вроде как равен 2, хотя точно не уверен, лень считать.

И еще простой пример, который разобьет вашу логику:

    1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1) + .... = 0

Comment: @BOPOH, ряд (-1)^n расходится и не имеет предела.

Comment: Чего-чего??? Это еще почему?

UPD: хотя может быть понял про что вы - если n задано, то от этого n зависит результат, -1, 0 или +1. Я вас правильно понял?

Кстати, мой последний пример не удовлетворяет условию Коши. Просто "Здравый смысл подсказывает мне..."))

Comment: Я про ряд 1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1) + ... (это и есть ряд (-1)^n). Вы написали, что "1 + (-1) + 1 + (-1) + .... = 0" Что вы этим имели ввиду?

Comment: Я же написал - "Здравый смысл подсказывает мне...")) Т.е. я сгруппировал нечетные с четными (в итоге равно 0), а 0 + 0 = 0, вот и написал. Когда написали вы - откинул здравый смысл. И правда, не сходится...

Хотя все равно "Здравый смысл подсказывает мне..."

Comment: Ну а если сгрупировать по-другому, то получится 1 + ((-1) + 1) + ((-1) + 1) + ... = 1 + 0 + 0 + ... = 1. =)

Comment: @BOPOH: ну, это же определение: нету предела частичных сумм — ряд расходится.

@Powervetall: вы знаете, после апорий Зенона в науке произошло серьёзное продвижение, почитайте об этом на досуге, вы будете удивлены.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну, смотрите.

Для начала, ваша сумма неправильно раскрыта: для `n = 0` имеем `x^0 / 0!`, то есть `1`, а не `x`.

Итак, начальное значение слагаемого `1`. Чтобы перейти к новому слагаемому на `i`-ой итерации, надо домножить на `x^2` и разделить на `(2*i - 1) * (2 * i)`. Дальше ясно?

Кстати, возведение в степень не нужно, если делать, так, как описано.

---

С другой стороны, известно, что для лучшей точности вычислений необходимо начинать суммирование с *наименьших* по модулю чисел. То есть, считать лучше с *конца*. Для этого превратим один цикл в два:

1. цикл от `i = 0`, `x = 1` пока `|x| >= eps` увеличиваем `i`, `x` домножаем на `x0 * x0` и делим на `(2*i - 1) * (2 * i)`
2. цикл пока `i >= 0` увеличиваем сумму на `x`, делим `x` на `x0 * x0` и домножаем на `(2*i - 1) * (2 * i)`, уменьшаем `i`

---

Как правильно было подмечено в комментариях, вычисляя слагаемые *дважды* (один раз на пути вправо, и один раз на пути влево), мы теряем точность. Выход — запоминать вычисленные элементы (для этого неплохо бы иметь автоматически растущий контейнер, наподобие `std::vector` в C++), или делать *три* прохода: один для вычисления количества слагаемых, второй для вычисления самих слагаемых и запоминания их, третий для суммирования с конца. Вместо первого прохода можно, по идее, грубо оценить количество слагаемых по условию выхода (`|x|^n/n! < eps <=> n ln |x| - ln n! < ln eps`), применив [формулу Стирлинга](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: >>для лучшей точности вычислений необходимо начинать суммирование с наименьших по модулю чисел

А это интересно. Где про это почитать можно? У Кнута?

Просто сомнительно как-то, если большие числа (т.е. первые в сравнении с последними слагаемыми) влияют на точность результата, то почему прибавление их не в начале, а в самом конце так же не повлияет на точность результата?

Или имеется ввиду что-то типа (для примера):

    0.004 + 0.004 (0.008) + 0.004 (0.01) + 1 (1.01) = 1.01
    1 + 0.004 (1.00) + 0.004 (1.00) + 0.004 (1.00) = 1.00

Comment: Да, что-то вроде того. Можете сами попробовать попрогонять программы для этих двух алгоритмов: прямого и обратного суммирования.

Comment: @VladD, Ваш второй алгоритм, суммирующий с конца, возможно будет еще хуже по точности, т.к., как известно, чем больше действий, то тем больше знаков теряется.
Хорошим вариантом этого избежать, смотрится сохранение промежуточных членов последовательности в массив, но вопрос сколько памяти это займет.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699066/in-which-order-should-floats-be-added-to-get-the-most-precise-result

Comment: >для лучшей точности вычислений необходимо начинать суммирование с наименьших по модулю чисел
ооо, спасибо ) новое для себя узнал ) и в принципе согласен с этим утверждением :)
> чем больше действий, тем больше знаков теряется
эту проблему можно обойти либо массивом, либо полным вычислением очередного члена последовательности :)
теряем либо дополнительно время, либо память, либо необходимо смириться с погрешностями :)

Comment: @gecube: хорошая идея. Тогда нужны _три_ прохода:

1. Вычислить количество слагаемых
2. Выделить память под них и запомнить слагаемые
3. Вычислить сумму с конца.

Первый шаг можно сделать за O(1), если логарифмировать и оценить факториал по формуле Стирлинга. Всего в любом случае выходит O(n) по времени и по памяти.

Comment: @Котик: для положительного `x` более-менее очевидно; для знакопеременного случая, и правда, возможно, лучше вначале сложить попарно и получить знакопостоянный ряд.

Comment: Я все же считаю что тут можно применить гнездование. К сожалению в свое время решая аналогичную задачу (вычисление синуса) мне не удалось решить из-за недопонимания, вопрос так же был где-то на хэшкоде. И мне почему то кажется что этот вариант будет более оптимизирован.

Comment: @Сергей: Вы бы хоть рассказали, что это такое :-) Если есть пример кода, почему бы не вам не написать альтернативный ответ? А если ещё и сравните точность...

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется он имеет в ввиду метод, аналогичный схеме Горнера. И похоже точность и вправду должна быть выше, хотя я и не знаюб как это доказать. Плюс нужно O(1) памяти.

Comment: @dzhioev: Хм, должно быть интересно. Но для схемы Горнера всё равно нужно предвычисление коэффициентов (т.к. они потребляются «справа налево»), так что от `O(n)` по памяти мы, кажется, не отделаемся. А вот точность вполне может и повыситься.

Comment: @VladD, не это в схеме Горнера для произвольного многочлена надо помнить коэффициенты (собственно они и подаются на вход). В нашем случае коэфициенты будут зависеть от номера шага:
![][1]

  [1]: http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=\sum_{i%3D0}^{N}%20\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}%20%3D%201%20%2B%20\frac%20{x^2}{2}%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20\frac%20{x^{2N}}{(2N)!}%20%3D%201%20%2B%20%20\frac{x^2}{1\cdot2}\left(1%20%2B%20\frac{x^2}{3\cdot4}\left(...\left(1%20%2B%20\frac{x^2}{(2N%20-%201)(2N)}%20\right)...\right)\right)&bc=White&fc=Black&im=png&fs=12&ff=arev&edit=0

Comment: @dzhioev: И правда. :-) Хорошая идея, кстати. Напишете свой ответ? Он того стоит. Но вам, кажется, всё же придётся делать _два_ прохода: найти `N` на первом и вычислить сумму на втором. (Коэффициенты будут фактически вычислены дважды, но повышение точности стоит того.)

Comment: А что мешает коэффициенты считать при углублении рекурсии?

Comment: @Сергей: К чему относится ваш коммернтарий? Если к вычислению по схеме Горенра, то во-первых, там нет никакой рекурсии, а во-вторых, коэффициенты не запоминаются по дороге для улучшения точности, так как финальный проход будет работать с меньшим количеством операций (смотрите формулу в комментарии выше). Если вы имеете в виду другой метод вычислений, я бы предложил опубликовать его как отдельный ответ.

Comment: Насколько я помню достаточно проверять текущее слагаемое и если оно меньше точности, пора сворачивать рекурсию

Comment: @Сергей: Не вижу, почему должно получиться, учитывая, что слагаемые появляются в порядке справа налево. Приведите код, а?

Comment: функция (аргументы)

      считаем прибавляемую часть

      если часть<точности

        возвращеем 0

      иначе

        возвращаем прибавляемая часть+функция(новые аргументы)

Comment: @Сергей, что такое по вашему прибавляемая часть?

Comment: @Сергей: ещё раз повторюсь: «прибавляемая часть» вычисляется по схеме Горнера справа налево. И если вы внимательно посмотрите в формулу в комментарии выше, вы увидите, что прибавляется всегда единица. Значит, условие «`если часть<точности`» есть константа. Поэтому у меня есть подозрение, что вы не сможете привести код.

Answer (score 1):

[@VlaD](/users/3776/vlad), комментарии закончились, решил выложить пример на питоне

```
# решение в лоб, суммируем слева направо
def check(x = 0, eps = 0):
    sumPart = 1.
    curSum = 0

    n = 1
    while sumPart > eps:
        curSum += sumPart
        sumPart = sumPart * x * x / (n * (n + 1))
        n += 2
    return curSum

# решение через рекурсию (по формуле @dzhioev), суммирование справа налево
def calc(x = 0, eps = 0, n = 1, mulPart = 1):
    sumPart = 1. * (x * x) / (n * (n + 1))
    stepSum = mulPart * sumPart
    if stepSum < eps:
        return 1
    return 1 + sumPart * calc(x, eps, n + 2, stepSum)

# хвостовая рекурсия, суммирование слева направо
def tailLRSum(x = 0, eps = 0, n = 1, mulPart = 1, result = 1):
    currentSumPart = 1. * (x * x) / (n * (n + 1))
    stepSum = mulPart * currentSumPart
    if stepSum < eps:
        return result
    return tailLRSum(x, eps, n + 2, stepSum, result + stepSum)

# хвостовая рекурсия, суммирование справа налево (используем lambda)
def tailRLSum(x = 0, eps = 0, n = 1, mulPart = 1, result = None):
    sumPart = 1. * (x * x) / (n * (n + 1))
    stepSum = mulPart * sumPart
    if result == None:
        result = lambda value: value
    if stepSum < eps:
        return result(0)
    return tailRLSum(x, eps, n + 2, stepSum, lambda value: result(1 + sumPart * value))
```

Как [видно](http://pastebin.com/XBzQnz5d) - каждый метод дает свои результаты.

Первые три - почти одни и те же, а вот последний ведет себя странно - точность у него не eps, а 10*eps. Т.е. если ему в проверке сделать if stepSum < eps * 0.1, то точность будет та, что нужна (вывод в скобках). И в данном случае (т.е. при eps * 0.1) точность будет выше, чем у остальных.

Для себя понял, что ни фига не знаю как все работает внутри. Ведь по сути (по крайней мере для меня) второй и четвертый вариант должны отрабатывать одинаково - сначала вычисляются правые члены, затем добавляются левые. Аналогично и первый и второй - сначала вычисляются левые, затем правые члены. Но видно в каком-то месте (для меня неочевидном) происходит потеря точности. Причем где-то в последнем методе вообще что-то не хорошее творится...

Насчет произвольной хвостовой рекурсии, дайте пример - посмотрю, а так ничего не скажу, т.к. не знаю.

Есть кто-нить, кто может прокомментировать результаты?

Comment: Кстати, в питоне хвостовая рекурсия отсутствует. Пример я привел чтобы можно было портировать на языки, где она есть.

Answer (score -1):

Методом гнездовых процедур

Comment: Дабы не захламлять верхний ответ продолжаю тут:

@dzhioev, уважаемый я не просто так сделал абстракцию на этом моменте.

Посмотрите формулу и сообразите сами, что там у вас высчитывается в функции рекурсии.

Comment: @VladD, если вы считаете, что прибавляется единица - вы не понимаете формулу, сами посмотрите прибавляется НЕ единица

Comment: Не знаю зачем я это пишу, ведь я уверен, что вы неправы. Я напишу вам рекурсивную функцию для вычисления (рекурсия, кстати, только вредит, т.к. использует O(n) памяти, в отличии от итеративного вычисления), без условия остановки, а вы мне напишите условие:

    double f(double x, int n) {
      if (/* условие которое вы должны написать */) {
        return 0.0;
      } else {
        return 1.0 + x * x / (2 * n - 1) / (2 * n) * f(x, n + 1);
      }
    }

Вперед.

Comment: x * x / (2 * n - 1) / (2 * n) < E

и еще мне почему то кажется что у вас в формуле ошибка, т.к. формулу обычно разрывают на плюсе.

так же в заголовке не хватает переменной точности (Е) для сравнения.

Comment: @Сергей: Это неправильно. В вопросе чётко указан критерий остановки: `x^2n / (2n)! < eps`.

Comment: @Сергей, в вопросе вообще-то явно написано:

>>"Вычислить... с точностью до eps... Считать, что требуемая точность достигнута, если очередное слагаемое по модулю меньше eps"

Очередное слагаемое - это слагаемое вида x^2n / (2n)!

Т.е. тов. @VladD, прав.

Если считать коэффициенты в рекурсии, то получится (если грубо):

    a + b * (c + (d))

Вы подсчитали коэффициенты в d, нашли что прибавление d Ничего не изменит и вышли из рекурсии. Но ведь прибавляется не d, а b * d, а оно будет больше e.

Хотя "здравый смысл подсказывает мне"... Надо подумать, если что сброшу алгоритм.

Comment: А так:

    def calc(x = 0, eps = 0, n = 1, mulPart = 1):
        sumPart = 1. * (x * x) / (n * (n + 1))
        stepSum = mulPart * sumPart
        if stepSum < eps:
            return 1
        return 1 + sumPart * calc(x, eps, n + 2, sumPart)

    def check(x = 0, eps = 0):
        sumPart = 1.
        curSum = sumPart
        n = 1
        while sumPart > eps:
            sumPart = sumPart * x * x / (n * (n + 1))
            curSum += sumPart
            n += 2
        return curSum

    x = 1
    eps = 0.0000000000001
    print check(x = x, eps = eps)
    print calc(x = x, eps = eps)

Comment: Хм... ну возможно данный метод и выходит за границы вопроса, однако он не менее интересен, по крайней мере мне)

Comment: @VladD, вы этот код просили от тов. @Сергей?

calc - используем рекурсию.

Чтобы узнать текущий слагаемый - ввел mulPart. Т.е. то, что в формуле за скобкой. Тогда проверка идет на текущий слагаемый из исходной формулы.

check - исходный алгоритм для проверки.

Comment: @BOPOH: А, вы объединили два прохода в один, вижу. Круто! (Но рекурсия не хвостовая.)

Comment: @VladD, насколько понимаю, при реализации хвостовой рекурсии придется складывать слева направо, но вы же сами говорили, что это не хорошо. Складывая "с конца" - увеличиваем точность, и ваши слова:

>>Коэффициенты будут фактически вычислены дважды, но повышение точности стоит того

Хотя при данных значениях изменения точности я не заметил.

Хвостовая рекурсия:

    def calc2(x=0, eps=0, n=1, mulPart=1, result=1):
        sumPart = 1.*(x*x) / (n*(n+1))
        stepSum = mulPart*sumPart
        if stepSum < eps:
            return result
        return calc2(x, eps, n+2, stepSum, result+stepSum)

Comment: @BOPOH: Угу, слева направо не очень хорошо. Более по-питоновски было бы, возможно, так: (1) создать генератор слагаемых слева направо, (2) развернуть полученный из генератора список (3) аккумулировать в сумму. Но это было бы не по Горнеру.

Кстати — неужели нету метода _произвольную_ рекурсию превратить в хвостовую?